# Issue while installing Odoo prerequisites

Tags: python, deployment, odoo-10

I am getting an error while installing Odoo community edition using the source code. I am following the steps mentioned in [guide](https://odootutorials.wordpress.com/2016/09/11/odoo-source-installation-on-windows/) to install Odoo on Windows 10 Home.

These are the steps I have executed so far;

1. I have installed Python and set the root folder in PATH variable
       e.g. C:\Python27;
2. I have installed Postgresql
3. I am getting error
   while installing prerequisites as C:\Python27\Scripts>pip
       install -r C:\unifiedexpert\odoo-11.0\requirements.txt

Am I missing anything?

```
    C:\Python27\Scripts\pip run on 10/31/17 10:57:38
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 262, in run
    for req in parse_requirements(filename, finder=finder, options=options, session=session):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1631, in parse_requirements
    req = InstallRequirement.from_line(line, comes_from, prereleases=getattr(options, "pre", None))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2583, in scan_list
    "Expected ',' or end-of-list in",line,"at",line[p:]
ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'xlwt==1.3.*', 'at', '*')
```

Comment: Replace 40th line of requirement.txt with xlwt==1.3.0

Comment: Which odoo version you are try to installing ?

Comment: Good catch @VikiChavada. This error had gone after changing xlwt with xlwt==1.3.0 (I guess * was causing a problem). keval I am trying to install Odoo 11.0.

Comment: Now I am getting another error if could help me to resolve it.  c:\users\nayyer\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-l0oe2g\pyldap\modules\errors.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Nayyer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2